# Sense HAT - Power Consumption

Tags: power, sensor, battery, sense-hat

What is the average power consumption of the official Sense HAT (**w/o LEDs**)?
More specifically:
I'm interested in the power consumption when **logging the data** from the gyroscope, accelerometer and humidity sensors **every second**.

I've been searching the official website, reseller websites and some forums but was unable to find any data related to the Sense HAT.
If any of you happens to have any data or know of some data related to the power consumption I would be pleased to know - general data different from my use case would also help.
I don't even know if it will be in the **region of tens or hundreds of mAs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were looking carefully this information and didn't find anything, I think that there is not an official power consumption about that, but I can tell you an approximation, the Sense HAT has no an external supply, so it just works with the power supply of the power port in GPIO Header of the RBPi. According to the [Schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/sense-hat/images/Sense-HAT-V1_0.pdf) it uses the 3.3V and 5V port, the 5V port is used to feed all the LEDs of the Sense HAT. These ports have current limitations 3.3v-50mA and 5v-750mA-2.5A (depends of which RBPi is used), an efficient LED take at most 10mA and there are 64 ColorLEDs (192 real LEDs "RGB") so at most 1920mA, with the other sensors takes like max 1970mA because all are connected to the 3.3V port and it takes just 50mA.

I tried to search the power consumption of the LEDs that the Sense Hat using but I didn't find anything, my suggestion is take like 3mA per LED, because those things are very efficient with the LEDs and this module can work over a RBPi A+ and this has just 700mA. Finally, my answer of your question with all the considerations that I explained above are at most 626mA, this is the maximum power consumption of the Sense HAT. I hope that it will be helful for you.

Comment: Yes, that was very helpful, thank you. That estimate is good enough and helped me to decide if my project is potentially doable :)